# Unity converting Character Controller code to Rigidbody code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a movement relative to the camera. Like Super Mario 64 etc. First i made it with a CharacterController but I want to have the default collision detection so I need to use a collider with a Rigidbody.

My code looks this:

```
    public class PlayerMovementController : PlayerCommonController
{
    PlayerMovementData data; // data class
    PlayerMovementView view; // animation, etc. ... class

    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    float speedSmoothVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        data = new PlayerMovementData();
        view = new PlayerMovementView();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 inputDirection = (new Vector2(data.InputHorizontal, data.InputVertical)).normalized; // get the inputs

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if (data.PlayerCharacterController.isGrounded) // player is on ground?
                data.VelocityY = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * data.PlayerGravity * data.JumpPower);
        }

        if (inputDirection != Vector2.zero) // Rotate the player
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(
                transform.eulerAngles.y, 
                Mathf.Atan2(inputDirection.x, inputDirection.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + data.CameraTransform.eulerAngles.y,
                ref turnSmoothVelocity,
                GetModifiedSmoothTime(data.TurnSmoothTime));
        }

        data.CurrentMovementSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp( /* Set the movementspeed */
            data.CurrentMovementSpeed, 
            data.MovementSpeed * inputDirection.magnitude,
            ref speedSmoothVelocity,
            GetModifiedSmoothTime(data.SpeedSmoothTime));

        data.VelocityY += data.PlayerGravity * Time.deltaTime; // vertical velocity

        Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * data.CurrentMovementSpeed + Vector3.up * data.VelocityY; // set the players velocity

        data.PlayerCharacterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime); // Move the player

        data.CurrentMovementSpeed = (new Vector2(data.PlayerCharacterController.velocity.x, data.PlayerCharacterController.velocity.z)).magnitude; // Calc movementspeed

        if (data.PlayerCharacterController.isGrounded) // Set the vertical vel. to 0 when grounded
            data.VelocityY = 0;
    }

    float GetModifiedSmoothTime(float smoothTime) // Handle the movement while in air
    {
        if (data.PlayerCharacterController.isGrounded)
            return smoothTime;

        if (data.AirControlPercentage == 0)
            return float.MaxValue;

        return smoothTime / data.AirControlPercentage;
    }
}
```

So it seems obvious to replace all the CharacterController variables with a Rigidbody key word. But when it comes to

```
data.PlayerCharacterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

I don't know what to replace there. When I got no CC but a Collider and a Rigidbody i drop through the ground. This may happen because of the code..

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `CharacterController` component from your player and attach a `Rigidbody` component. Then use

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

I will suggest that you create a reference of you attached rigidbody and use it instead of `GetComponent`.

Comment: Hm this works almost fine. The player is falling down very very slowly. And I can not move him. My current code looks this: https://hastebin.com/axexuwakup.cs     I highly believe that my VelocityY is not correct. My Rigidbody uses gravity and I calculate it there too. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please note that you are now in the physics world, therefore, you will have to tweak your velocity value (close to reality). and yes rigidbody has its own gravity you don't need to calculate it.